# Elasticsearch path_hierarchy tokenizes half of the path

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I am trying to index a path using path_hierarchy tokenizer but it seems to be tokenize-ing only half of the path i providing. I have tried with different paths and the results seem to be the same.

My settings are -

```
{
    "settings" : { 
        "number_of_shards" : 5,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
                "keylower":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer":"keyword",
                    "filter":"lowercase"
                },
                "path_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "path_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "path_ngrams" ]
                },
                "code_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "code_stemmer" ]
                },
                "not_analyzed": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "code_stemmer" ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "path_tokenizer": {
                  "type": "path_hierarchy"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "path_ngrams": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 15
                },
                "code_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "minimal_english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My mapping is as follows -

```
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "depot_path": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "path_analyzer"
    }
  },
  "_all": {
      "store": "yes",
      "analyzer": "english"
  }
}
```

I provided `"//cm/mirror/v1.2/Kolkata/ixin-packages/builds/"` as `depot_path` on analyzing I have found that tokens formed as follows -

```
               "key": "//c",
               "key": "//cm",
               "key": "//cm/",
               "key": "//cm/m",
               "key": "//cm/mi",
               "key": "//cm/mir",
               "key": "//cm/mirr",
               "key": "//cm/mirro",
               "key": "//cm/mirror",
               "key": "//cm/mirror/",
               "key": "//cm/mirror/v",
               "key": "//cm/mirror/v1",
               "key": "//cm/mirror/v1.",
```

**Why is it that the entire path is not tokenized?**

My expected output is to have tokens formed all the way upto `//cm/mirror/v1.2/Kolkata/ixin-packages/builds/`

**I have tried increasing the buffer-size but no luck. Does anyone know what is it that I'm doing wrong?**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"max_gram": 15` is limiting token size to 15. If you increase `"max_gram"` , you would see further path will be tokenized.

Below is example from my env.

```
"max_gram" :15 
input path : /var/log/www/html/web/
path_analyser tokenized this path upto /var/log/www/ht i.e. 15 characters
```

```
 "max_gram" :100
    input path : /var/log/www/html/web/WANTED
    path_analyser tokenized this path upto /var/log/www/html/web/WANTED i.e. 28  characters <100
```

Comment: Thanks :) I decided to simply get rid of `path_ngrams` filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've set the value of `"max_gram"` to `15`. Hence you'll notice that the largest token generated ("//cm/mirror/v1.") is of length `15`. Change it to a very large number and you'll get your desired tokens.

Comment: Thanks :) Accepting Shubhangi's answer as she beat you by 16 secs . :)